# Type mismatch in django serializer for request parsing

Tags: python, django, serialization, django-models

I had created the following serializers for request parsing of JSON data. However, while performing the operation, I get an unexpected error.

```
class A(serializers.ModelSerializer):            
    class Meta:                                                
        model = CName                                  
        fields = ('id','contact','email')                      
        read_only_fields=('contact',)                            

class B(serializers.ModelSerializer):      
    class Meta:                                                
        model = PName                                    
        fields = ('id','contact','number')                    
        read_only_fields=('contact',)              

class C(serializers.ModelSerializer):          
    contact_number = A(many=True)          
    contact_email = B(many=True)                

    class Meta:                                                  
        model = Contact                                          
        fields = ('id','name','contact_number','contact_email')  

    def create(self,validated_data):         
        contact_number=validated_data.pop('contact_number')      
        contact_email =validated_data.pop('contact_email')      
        instance = Contact.objects.create(**validated_data)            
        for number in contact_number:                                                           
            PName.objects.create(contact=instance,**number)      
        for email in contact_email:                                    
            CName.objects.create(contact=instance,**email)      
        return instance

    def update(self, instance, validated_data):                  
        contact_number=validated_data.pop('contact_number')      
        contact_email =validated_data.pop('contact_name')            
        Contact.objects.filter(id=instance.id).update(**validated_data)
        number_to_keep=[]                                              
        email_to_keep=[]                                              
        for number in contact_number:                                  
            if number.get('id'):                                      
                ph_id = number.pop('id')                              
                PName.objects.filter(id=ph_id).update(**number)  
                number_to_keep.append(ph_id)                          
            else:                                                      
                ph=PName.objects.create(contact=instance,**number)
                number_to_keep.append(ph.id)                            
        for email in contact_email:                                    
            if email.get('id'):                                        
                em_id = email.pop('id')                                
                CName.objects.filter(id=em_id).update(**email)  
                email_to_keep.append(em_id)                            
            else:                                                        
                em = CName.objects.create(contact=instance,**email)
                email_to_keep.append(em.id)                              
        instance.contact_number.exclude(id__in=number_to_keep).delete()  
        instance.contact_email.exclude(id__in=email_to_keep).delete()     
        return instance
```

**I have a json-format where I am passing the request data in the format(I will have strings only):**

```
{
"contact_number": "9999999999",
"contact_email":"timsh@hotmail.com"
}
```

While calling up the serializer using the following code:

```
contact_details = Contact.objects.get(rest = rest)
contact_serializer = ContactSerializer(contact_details,data=request.data)
```

I received the response as below:

```
{
    "contact_number": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Expected a list of items but got type \"unicode\"."
        ]
    },
    "contact_email": {
        "non_field_errors": [
            "Expected a list of items but got type \"unicode\"."
        ]
    }
}
```

**Note: I cannot have the data format of JSON in the below format:**

```
{
"contact_number" : [
                    { "number" : "9999999999"
                     }
],
"contact_email" : [
                    { "email" : "tim@hotmail.com"
                     }
]
}
```

Can anyone please suggest what changes could be done in the serializer so that I could overcome the issue here.

Answer (score 0):

```py
class A(serializers.ModelSerializer):            
    class Meta:                                                
        model = CName                                  
        fields = ('id','contact','email')                      
        read_only_fields=('contact',)  

    def save(self, **kwargs):
        [obj.save(**kwargs) for obj in self]
```

Use custom save method while saving.

Comment: Hi @teja reddy , I added the save method in both the serializers A and B. But still the error exists.

Comment: Hi @teja reddy, I explicitly mentioned that I cannot have this format in my post. I want to have these as a key in the dictionary with strings. Please go through the post once again.

Comment: @Timshrok did you use the same save method which i have mentioned above, if so please customise the save method as per your requirement , i have just gave you a sample example or otherwise use clean method

Comment: @Timshrok i feel there may be and encoding issue please refer to https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/serialization/#djangojsonencoder

Comment: Hi @teja reddy. I have sorted the above error. But now the update method in serializer 'C' is not being called.

Comment: Hi @teja reddy, can you please suggest help. As to why this update method may not be called?

Comment: @Timshrok i suggest you to refer https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30409076/when-are-create-and-update-called-in-djangorestframework-serializer